# Can you check if an address is a contract or an EOA with eth-brownie or some other python native package?

Tags: python, brownie

I'm trying to categorize smart contracts versus EOAs since I am treating them differently in an application. Does anyone have ideas?

I know in solidity you could try `address.code.length` or `extcodesize` (for most use cases).

Answer (score 5):

web3.py has [web3.eth.get_code](https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/web3.eth.html#web3.eth.Eth.get_code).

> Returns the bytecode for the given account at the block specified by block_identifier.

From the examples in the documentation

```
# For a contract address.
>>> web3.eth.get_code('0x6C8f2A135f6ed072DE4503Bd7C4999a1a17F824B')
'0x6060604052361561027c5760e060020a60003504630199.....'
# For a private key address.
>>> web3.eth.get_code('0xd3CdA913deB6f67967B99D67aCDFa1712C293601')
'0x'
```